# how display contexts of two different app and different view in one template in one project in django?

Tags: python, django, templates, jinja2

i have a project with different views and different function on it.
i want to access and display context of one of view in other html app.
this my code

washer.views.py

```
def Product_list_view(request):
    product_list_view = Product.objects.all()
    best_post = Product.objects.order_by('timefield')[0:2]
    context = {
       "product_list_view": product_list_view,
       'best_post':best_post
    }
    template_name = "product_list_view.html"
    return render(request,template_name,context)
```

gasket.views.py

```
  def home(request):
     template= "base.html"
     return render(request,template,context={})
```

how i can access context of product_list_view and show it in base.html ?
can i set one html to two different views in different app ? and access to context both of them ?
what i have to do ? 
tnx for help me .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're actually trying to achieve here but you could simply rewrite `gasket.views.py` as

```
def home(request):
     template= "base.html"
     context = {
         "product_list_view": Product.objects.all(),
         'best_post':Product.objects.order_by('timefield')[0:2]
     }
     return render(request,template,context={})
```

Clearly you will need to add `from washer.models import Product`

Comment: this is my main problem when i want product in antoher app in this suituion gasket 
when i write code you did write get error i go to up directory :

from gasket.washer.models import Product 
get this error : 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gasket.washer'
i know if i import model Product i can solve my probelm .

Comment: have you included it in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'comments',
    'washer',
    'newsletters',
    'taggit',
]
yes i did it before i have probelm with this i want to have best product and newsletter ... in base page but i can't import them to base app and use them .

Comment: What is the file structure?  Your error is ` No module named 'gasket.washer' ` but I don't know why `gasket` is there

Comment: can't access Product so i go to up directory of washer that is gasket but now i get this error with this picutre : https://pasteboard.co/I8s43qj.png

Comment: It should work.  Go through slowly looking for typos

Comment: it 's worked problem was for my editor pycharm. tnx dude for help.